# Vue component in a loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

In the simplified example below, it prints a table and the last column is a component. When I change the component by changing the test variable it changes the components in every single row. Is there a way to just change the component in one row, without making changes to the entries variable? FYI: In the real example the component is defined using a slot, and so I am restricted to the parent scope.

```
<template>
<tr v-for="entry in entries">
   <td v-for="key in columns">
       {{entry[key]}}
   </td>
   <component v-bind:is="test"></component>
</tr>
</template>
```

Comment: How about making the `test` variable into an array so you can have one value for each row? I.e. `test = [1,2,3,4]` and then use `v-for="(entry, index) in entries"` in the first loop to extract an index for the row, then use that in the component like this `v-bind:is="test[index]"`. Does that make sense?

Comment: The values in `entries` could even contain the test varibale so you could do something like this in your component `v-bind:is="enrty.test"`.

Comment: You should consider binding `:key` in each `v-for`. 
`v-for="(entry, index) in entries" :key="index` for example

Comment: How would that help? I'm not familiar with that